# Warning: "SOCKS Gateway was specified but is ignored"

Tags: socks-proxy, fiddler

I have putty (plink) set up as a SOCKS proxy listening on a local port, and it works fine in my browsers via a PAC script.

However, when I configure Fiddler (4.6.2.2) to use it as a gateway with `socks=192.168.123.123:1234`, it ignores it.

"Show current gateway info" gives me this (doesn't matter if I use `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or the local IP):

[image: SOCKS Gateway was specified but is ignored]

*(the rectangles in the IP address are down to my MS Paint skills, not something weird from Fiddler)*

Google doesn't find anything for that particular error. Restarting Fiddler doesn't help. Proxy is definitely running. Any idea what would cause this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found an answer to the *why* (it may just be that Fiddler doesn't allow setting a global SOCKS proxy, not that that makes any sense to me), but there is a workaround.

Adding the following to `OnBeforeRequest` in Custom Rules (FiddlerScript) will set the SOCKS proxy per-request, which then works as intended:

```
oSession["x-OverrideGateway"] = "socks=127.0.0.1:1234";
```

More info including how to selectively set proxy for different URLs at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/httpfiddler/6m2xEe0fRmw/_NWAlNzn5eEJ
and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/httpfiddler/XQCBvVawsLw